# Wordpress white screen front-end

Tags: php, wordpress

I know there are a thousand white-screen issues posted about wordpress, but for some reason I can't find the answer.

1. I have disabled all plugins.
2. I have switched to a default theme.
3. This is an identical copy of wordpress (incl. database) from one localhost install to another localhost install. Same ports, same users, everything the same. The other one works.
4. The admin page works just fine, the "front-end" just shows a white page with no errors logged.

I'm running PHP 7.1

A small "side note" - I added an index.html file that won't list at the root url, only if I type in url.com/index.html does it come up - perhaps related?

I started with a fresh database just now, the problem still persists. The server shows plenty of access log attempts but zero errors. I'm starting to think this is an apache conf issue even though I have copied the default from WP many times and verified it's being read.

Comment: Try to print something in index.php in root.

Comment: That works. Next?

Comment: If debug mode is false, do true and check errors. If it's true and still white, tell me how do you you log in to admin? what url?

Comment: Are you sure you server's error logs are empty? No complaints about .htaccess or public access?

Comment: localhost:8000/wp-login.php

debug is true, no errors

Comment: If you can not see the logs it means you need to enable Display Logs through CPANEL OR PLESK

Comment: all errors were just warnings, and are all cleaned up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Wordpress has a built-in Debug function, you just need to enable it through **wp-config.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

From now on you should be able to view where's the error is coming from.

2- White screen is a result of a lack of PHP memory. Add this line as well to your **wp-config**:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

3- Just to be sure download latest version of wordpress from https://wordpress.org/ and then Upload only wp-admin | wp-includes and other *.php files that are outside the folders.

4- You might also want to check your `.htaccess` and make sure it looks standard like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: THis wasn't the answer per se, but when I did end up re-downloading core, I discovered I had a one-off setting in my wp-config for reverse proxy look up - a nuance from the live site I had forgotten about.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer! and I am Glad you got it sort out! this is likely to happen again if you do not make sure your folders and files have the proper group and owner permission ( use your FTP and right click a file or folder > properties make sure all files and folder have same )

Answer (score 0):

Put in wp.config:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

Also, verify .htaccess

Comment: Tried that. Still no luck. Maybe I'm viewing my logs wrong? I have var/logs/apache2/error.log - if I try to cat it, it doesn't show any data?  I'm using the default Docker wordpress image based on Alpine Linux.

Comment: Can you check the website?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: The page is still white?

Comment: Yes. Trying to make sure I'm really seeing logs right now - I see access logs, just no error logs.

Comment: Test a basic DB connection from the index.php in root.